# Cannot use entry_points

Tags: python, setuptools

I am trying to learn about entry_points and how to use Python from the command line. My OS is Linux (Mint 15), and I tried unsuccessfully with both Python 2.7.4 and 3.3.1 -- with virtualenv.

`foo/setup.py`:

```
setup(
name='foo',
version='0.0.1',
description='foo',
url='http://www....',
author='Foo',
author_email='xxx@xxx.com',
install_requires = ['docopt', 'termcolor'],
packages = ['foo'],
entry_points = {
    'console_script': [
        'foo = foo.main:start'
    ],
},
```

)

`foo\foo\main.py`:

```
def start():
   print 'test'
```

`foo\foo\__init.py__`: empty

I installed with: `python setup.py develop`

```
(learn27)user@machine /data/apps/learn27/rocks $ python setup.py develop
running develop
... more output here
```

But when trying to run "foo" from the command line, it simply says "command not found". I could not find any file named "foo" onthe file system.

As far as I understand, I was expecting the generated executables to be located in the bin folder here:

```
>>> print distutils.sysconfig.get_config_var('prefix')
/data/apps/virtenvs/learn27
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entry point is called `console_scripts`, plural, you misspelled it as `console_script` (singular).

See [Automatic Script Creation](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html?highlight=console_scripts#automatic-script-creation) in the `setuptools` documentation.

Answer (score -2):

You may have to add it to your PATH

Comment: The scripts are not generated *at all*.